# non-english characters in wordpress url cause 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, url, urlencode

I have a wordpress website built with a template which doesn't support non-english characters in username. With a plugin installed, users now can use utf-8 characters in their username (like Chinese characters). but I noticed that some of the links are broken (pages couldn't be found,404 error), since these links have username (Chinese characters) as part of the url.

With my limited knowledge on wordpress, I think I need to modify the rewrite rules to accept uft8 characters in url.

For example, a url page

> 'website-domain/users/username1/likes'

works well with default rewrite rule:

```
 'regex'     => '^users/([a-z0-9_-]+)/likes/?$',
```

I changed the rule to:

```
 'regex'     => '^users/([a-z0-9_-\p{Han}]+)/likes/?$'
```

And hope it could handle urls with Chinese characters in the username. like

> 'website-domain/users/测试用户/likes'.

However, I got 404 error on it. With a debug tool, I saw the url used to match rewrite rules was like:

'users%2F%25e6%25b5%258b%25e8%25af%2595%25e7%2594%25a8%25e6%2588%25b7%2Flikes'.

So with Chinese character inside the url, the link has been encoded.

I guess one way to fix the problem is to force the url to decode before rewrite rule matching, but I don't know where and how to add the decode function. Could someone help?

Is there any other better ways to do this? Please feel free to share.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: URLs cannot handle unicode characters. In fact, there are even non-unicode characters that URLs cannot handle correctly. When you see these characters in a URL, the web browser is actually doing some helpful automatic conversions between percent-encoded URLs and their unicode representations, allowing you to see unicode characters in the address bar when viewed in the browser. Your web server, however, is going to see the percent-encoded version of this URL. Do you have access to an `index.php` file of some sort? If so, you could probably overwrite `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress myself, so without knowing which tools you're using, I can't really do any more detailed research into a best-practices solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, B. Fleming. I have full access to all files in this wordpress website but I'm not familiar with wordpress architect and php programming language. I'm not sure if I should decode the URL and then match the regex rules or if there's a way to create a new regex rule to match the encoded url? If I should go with decoding, I need help to know where to add the decode function. Thanks.